# Angular Unit Testing injecting parameters

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, inject

i am trying to setup unit tests using inject. But i am not sure how to set the parameters.

The constructor for the class being tested (auth.service.ts) is:

```
constructor(private http : HttpClient, private token: TokenStorage) {}
```

Unit Test class (auth.service.spec.ts)

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TokenStorage } from './token.storage';

describe('AuthService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [AuthService, HttpClient, HttpHandler, HttpClientModule, TokenStorage]
        });
    });
    it('should be created', inject([AuthService], (service: AuthService) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-http-services

Comment: The tag [tag:angular] is for [angular.io](https://angular.io) (2+) and tag [tag:angularjs] is for [angularjs.org](https://angularjs.org/) (1x). Using the correct tag will help give your question visibility to developers that can better answer your question.

Comment: Something which can be helpful https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-services-in-angular-karma-ed49f8d5b264

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use the `HttpClientTestingModule` to test `HttpClient` usage in your service.
2. Use a fake value for `TokenStorage`, otherwise your unit test becomes an integration test.

See also [angular - Testing services with the TestBed](https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-services-with-the-testbed)

```
import { TestBed, inject, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { TokenStorage } from './token.storage';

describe('AuthService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: AuthService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        { provide: TokenStorage, useValue: {} }
      ]
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(AuthService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I get the following error:

Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AuthService -> HttpClient]: 
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'AuthService', Function ] })